# Changing == to === in if(window.location == 'x') causes the block not to execute

Tags: javascript, equals-operator, triple-equals

I'm checking over my code for uses of `==` instead of `===`, but changing this line:

```
if(window.location == 'app:/test.html')
```

To this:

```
if(window.location === 'app:/test.html')
```

Results in the block no longer being executed.

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because `===` matches the type as well as the contents.

`window.location` acts like a `string` in most cases, but is actually a `Location` object.

You can change your `if` to check the `href` property, which is a `string`:

```
if(window.location.href === 'app:/test.html')
```

Your code will then work as intended!

MDN has [a decent article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) about `window.location` that's worth a read.